react-native-swiper-flatlist - scrollToIndex out of range: requested index undefined but minimum is 0
im currently learning how to develop apps with react-native, im using expo as a way to deploy my app to my iPhone to check it out.
im using react-native-swiper-flatlist as my swiper of screens.
i have the following code for a signUp page that im attempting to write:
<SwiperFlatList ref={swiperRef} index={0} showPagination>
        <FullName firstName={firstName} setfirstName={setfirstName} />
        <Email email={email} setEmail={setEmail} /> 
      </SwiperFlatList>

    
    <Pressable
       onPress={()=>{console.log(JSON.stringify(swiperRef)); swiperRef.current.scrollToIndex(swiperRef.current.getCurrentIndex() + 1)}}
       style={({ pressed }) => [{ borderColor: pressed ? 'black' : 'white', backgroundColor: pressed ? '#f8b996' : '#ffffff' }, styles.button ]}>
       {({ pressed }) => (

         <Text style={[{ color: pressed ? 'white' : '#000000' }]}>
          proceed
         </Text>
       )}
     </Pressable>


i use: swiperRef = useRef(null)
at the beginning of my function.
the console log of swiperRef prints that swiperRef.current == {}, and the error is triggered by this:
swiperRef.current.scrollToIndex(swiperRef.current.getCurrentIndex() + 1)}

The error is this:
"scrollToIndex out of range: requested index undefined but minimum is 0"
also, if it could provide help to solve this issue, FullName and Email are two components that i wrote that request the user to input data into  and i send over to those components their respective state & setState.
I hope you could help me solve my problem!
